# adding string at the end of a string for date time data format in R

Tags: r, datetime, data-cleaning

**My code:**

```
dates<- c("2012/2/06 15:47","2012-02-06 15:02:20")
for(i in 1: length(dates))
{
if(nchar(dates[i]) <= 16)
{ 
paste0(dates[i],":00")
}

}
library(stringr)
dates1=str_replace_all(dates,"/","-")


dates_strptime = strptime(dates1,format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

**Expected output:** 
 "2016-07-22 15:47:00 IST" "2017-06-08 15:02:20 IST"
**What i am getting :** 
 "NA" "2017-06-08 15:02:20 IST"

I am getting this result because the 1st object in the vector isn't in proper format .To get it into format i need to add :00 at the end of the string.
However , the paste0 doesn't work with y logic.

Am i doing something wrong .

I have a date time data format data .For example dates<- c("2016/**7**/22 **15:47**","2017-**06**-08 **15:02:20**")

If you will look into the 1st datetime  format in the vector, 07 is written as 7 & seconds time is missing from time i.e %H%m%s .

what i want to do is, i want to add :00 at the end of 15:47 .It again depends like we have to figure out where it is missing.

What i have done is calculating nchar(dates) .If nchar(dates) is <= 16 , then i want to add :00 at the end of the string .

Comment: `lubridate::parse_date_time(dates, c("ymd_HMS", "ymd_HM"), tz = "Asia/Calcutta")`

Comment: This was helpful.Thanks a lot !

Comment: You haven't assigned the return value, `dates[i] <- paste0(dates[i],":00")`.

Comment: If there is an extra `:00` at the end it will just ignore it so using the same time zone specifier as in @d.b.'s comment this does it with no packages: 
`as.POSIXct(paste0(gsub("/", "-", dates), ":00"), tz = "Asia/Calcutta")`